# Hide softkey board unknown error. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity with three EditText and a button. The below code is written inside the OnClickListener of the button.

```java
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

The system shows the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.View.getWindowToken()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentFocus()` returns null in case of throwing this error. Try below snippet:

```java
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View focus = getCurrentFocus();
if(focus == null) {
    focus = new View(this);
}
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focus.getWindowToken(), 0);
```